# If $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a+$ and $g(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, then $g(x)/f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to a+$ - are there any counterexamples?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Attempt :

$a<x<a+\delta \rightarrow |f(x)|<\epsilon$

Therefore,

$\dfrac{1}{|f(x)|}$ > $\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

since, $|g(x)| \geq 1$,

$\dfrac{|g(x)|}{|f(x)|}$ > $\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

by choosing $M = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

$\dfrac{|g(x)|}{|f(x)|}$ > $M$

Here I cannot get rid of the absolute value of $f(x)$ to finish the proof. I saw a counter-example for this one as $f(x) = x sin(\dfrac{1}{x})$ and $g(x) = 1$. But since we are in the extended real numbers, That's also work right?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: $g(x)=1, a=0, f(x)=-x$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you. can you elaborate on the counter-example I mentioned?

Comment: That example  also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since the statement is false. Take $f(x)=-x$, $a=0$, and $g(x)=1$. Then$$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac1x=-\infty.$$

Comment: Oh I have not seen it. What about $x sin(\dfrac{1}{x})$ and $g(x)=1$ ?

Comment: In that case, the limit doesn't exist.